# Map over string array and create property's for an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I know this is a basic question, but I am trying to create a data structure that is baffling me at the moment.

I have a string array like so:

```
let stringArray = ['Core', 'Regional'];
```

And I would like to create this data structure:

```
[
  {'key': 'Core', 'text': 'Core'},
  {'key': 'Regional', 'text': 'Regional'}
]
```

How can I `.map` over the stringArray to create the data structure above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution

```js
let stringArray = ['Core', 'Regional'];

stringArray = stringArray.map(str => ({key: str, text: str}));

console.log(stringArray);
```

Comment: In 10 minutes I can ser :)